# Sentry logs tracker doesn't worked as real-time

Tags: django, sentry, raven

I have a `django` project and set on this `raven` `sentry` client for logger handling, and I bring up a `sentry` server as dockerize.

when I tracking logs I need to **refresh** for logs view and real-time button doesn't work for me.

[image: sentry page screen shot]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The real-time update feature seem to be not working at all.
There's [an issue](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/4689) on GitHub and a [PR](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/pull/4976) related to it yet neither seem to be related to the feature is completely broken so I've raised a new issue:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/8355

**EDIT**: I've tried again now and it seems to be working again. Perhaps it was not working temporarily.

Comment: my Sentry version is 8.22.0 and not working real-time logs tracker, is this repaired in newer version?